# Convert dwg to pdf on AutoCAD

Tags: vba, autocad

Hi how can I Plot to Pdf my AutoCAD drawing using VBA? I Tried

```
Sub PlotToPdf()
ThisDrawing.ActiveLayout.ConfigName = "DWF6 ePlot.pc3"
Dim plotFileName As String
plotFileName = "Z:\USERS\KweziM\PROJECT S\MyPlot.pdf"

Dim result As Boolean

result = ThisDrawing.Plot.PlotToFile(plotFileName)
End Sub
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

That last line should be a subroutine call, not a function call... it should look like this

```
ThisDrawing.Plot.PlotToFile plotFileName
```

You do not need the `result` variable.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Public Sub VBAplot()
    Dim currentplot As AcadPlot
    Set currentplot = ThisDrawing.Plot

    ThisDrawing.ActiveLayout.ConfigName = "PDFCreator" ' Your plot device.
    ThisDrawing.ActiveLayout.CanonicalMediaName = "A4"

    ThisDrawing.ActiveLayout.StandardScale = acScaleToFit
    ThisDrawing.Application.ZoomExtents
    currentplot.PlotToDevice


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but this gives me an "invalid input" error on line 4 of the code.`ThisDrawing.ActiveLayout.ConfigName = "PDFCreator"`

Comment: PDFCreator is the external application. Virtual PDF Plotter. I suppose You don' have installed it. so You should use some other PDF plotter or "pc3" configuration file.

Comment: In AutoCAD You have few build-in drivers to save to PDF like 

"DWG To PDF.pc3"

"AutoCad PDF (General Documentation).pc3"

"AutoCad PDF (High Quality Print).pc3"

use one of them